# How to display total number of posts Wp rest api in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, axios

I'm new to Vuejs and I try simple fetch WP Rest Api with axios. I'm trying to get total number of posts and display that number. I know how to achieve with jQuery:

```
 $.get( 'localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', function( data, status, request ) 
   {
numPosts = request.getResponseHeader('x-wp-total');
 console.log( numPosts ); 
 });
```

How to do this with axios? I try like this.

```
   new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
     total: []
     },
  mounted() {
   axios.get("localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
   .then(response => {this.total = response.headers('x-wp-total').total})
 }
 });
```

And output:

```
  <div id="app">
       <p>
         {{total}}
      </p>

   </div>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Try `this.total = response.headers['x-wp-total']`

Comment: @DelenaMalan yes I get (" Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: response is not defined")

Comment: Are you getting the data from a service running on your localhost? If so, try adding `http://` to your url, e.g. `axios.get("http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")`. You might need to add the port number as well. Or if the `localhost` in your url is actually part of the url, try pre-fixing it with `/`, e.g. `.get("/localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")`

Comment: I would suggest to log any possible errors with .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data.errors)). You should also prepend http:// or https:// to your url.